# Resume fragment when switching back from a another fragment in android(Java)

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments

> **I heve read all the answers related this.**

I have 2 buttons, both opens different fragment.

when I open a fragment, do something with it, open another fragment and come back to the first fragment then I see all the changes I made are not applied, because fragment restarted.
Please help me..

**Activity**

```
    package com.example.canvastag;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.canvastag.fragments.firstFrag;
import com.example.canvastag.fragments.secondFrag;

public class asking extends AppCompatActivity {
    firstFrag frag1;
    secondFrag frag2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_asking);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.frag1button);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.frag2button);
        frag1 = new firstFrag();
        frag2 = new secondFrag();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag1, "").commit();
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag2, "").commit();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Fragment 1**

```
public class firstFrag extends Fragment {
View view;
TextView textView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        textView=view.findViewById(R.id.textFrag);
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("button clicked");
            }
        });

     return view;
    }
}
```

**Fragment 2-**

```
public class secondFrag extends Fragment {
View view;
TextView textView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        textView=view.findViewById(R.id.textFrag);
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("button seocnd clicked");
            }
        });

     return view;
    }
}
```

I want to resume fragment when I come back to it, not restart.

**OUTPUT-**

[image]

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag1, "").commit();
```

Try using:

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag1, "").commit();
```

Note:

You can add this to the fragment transaction: `addToBackStack(null)` so your previous state will be added to the backstack allowing you to go back with the back button.

Comment: thanks , I tried but it crashes the app when returning back,

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: firstFrag{2e09a2a4 #0 id=0x7f080056

Comment: You can add a tag to every fragment that you add like this: add(frag1, "frag_1_tag"), and then check if that fragment exists and removing it before adding another one:
Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("frag_1_tag");
if (oldFragment != null) {
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
}

Comment: but this way we are also reloading fragment? i want all the changes in the memory...

Comment: In you question you said that you want to go back and forth between your 2 fragments while keeping the changes. You can then use the check if the fragment exists that i shared in the previous comment and basically return from that function so you can not make more then 1 instance of the same fragment. That way you can only make 1 instance of each fragment that hold their own changes.

Comment: sitll does not work, I tried.

How can I show that fragment which I have already added but its not visible bcz I have loaded another fragment? 
we are adding two fragment one by one so only newest fragment will be visible,,, how can I show the older fragment again ?
thank you..